# Performance of functions in turn

Tags: ios, swift, func

I have two functions.
The first is a function with animation and the second is where I show the text on the screen.
I launch the functions from the button and when shaking the device but they work simultaneously.

I need to first execute the animation and then the text was displayed on the screen.
And you could do this, for example, once every few seconds.

So far there is this code:

```
@IBAction func startButtnAtion(_ sender: UIButton) {
    animateImage()
}

override  func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
        animateImage()
    }
}

func animateImage() {
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
    rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0
    backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    answerForQuest()
}

func answerForQuest() {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you use `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(_ block: (() -> Void)?)` so animation method will look like this:

```swift
func animateImage() {
    CATransaction.begin() // 1
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:
            "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
    rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { //2
        self.answerForQuest()
    }
    backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit() //3
 }
```

---

Typically, you can switch from `CABasicAnimation` to use `class func animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)` from `UIView` class so you animation will look similar to this one:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration:2.0, animations: {
    self.backGroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
}, completion: { completed in
    self.answerForQuest()
})
```

But it won't in your case, as it is calculating the difference between the start and end state, and animating the only what has changed.

---

You can create a variable that will tell if there is an ongoing animation, and don't allow to start a new one until previous will ended:

```swift
@IBAction func startButtnAtion(_ sender: UIButton) {
    animateImage()
}

var isAnimating: Bool = false //1
func animateImage(){
    guard !isAnimating else { //2
        return
    }
    isAnimating = true //3
    CATransaction.begin()
    let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:
        "transform.rotation")
    rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi * 4
    rotationAnimation.duration = 2.0
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        self.answerForQuest()
    }
    backGroundImage.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()

}

func answerForQuest()
{
    isAnimating = false //4
    print("answerForQuest")
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, thanks. But there remains one more task. I have a button that launches all this in action, and I can click how many times it is pleasing. How can, for example, limit the user to one button in 3 seconds

Comment: I think you can set `isEnabled = false` at the beginning of  `animateImage` to disable button (and then set it to `true` in `answerForQuest()`). Check my edited response.

Comment: Fine ! It works, thanks.
But I still need to do this for shaking. That it would be possible to disconnect as a button when the animation started

Comment: So maybe you can add a variable that tells if the animation is in progress. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: @GlebSeredyuk could you check my edit, and let me know if it is working for you?

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate (CAAnimationDelegate) for the first animation to your view controller. Listen for the animationDidStop event to be triggered and once it is triggered to run your second animation (of showing the text). This will allow for the first animation to finish executing before starting your next animation.

Documentation regarding CAAnimationDelegate can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationdelegate).